# Show base64 String of different files in WebView

Tags: android

Currently  i am getting `Base64` encoded String from server and this `Base64` can be pdf file or can be other formats like `.doc, .xls, .ppt, .jpg, .png, .mov, .txt` etc. so how can i load this `Base64` in `WebView` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in case of opening it in webview it will better to open the file using default installed application in android. For example, the following code will open a pdf file:--

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(“your file path”);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

For this to work, you must decode the base64 data to actual file. Then you can fire the intent for that file. You also will need to provide mime type of the file to open. In the above example "**application/pdf**" is the mime type for pdf files. Android system will automatically display list of installed application that can be used to open the file.

You can find list of mime types [from this link.](https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

Open File using Direct URL from server. Don't convert your file.

Use Google Drive Weburl to load the file url.

```
     @BindView(R.id.webView)
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_any_doc);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        String url = "http://www.adobe" +
                ".com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
        String googleDoc = "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=";


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

//        String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=+location to your PDF File+'
//        width='100%' height='100%'
//        style='border: none;'></iframe>";


        final Activity activity = this;

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });


        webView.loadUrl(googleDoc + url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }


        });
    }
```

Find the XML below!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.aw.avi.allutilsmethodsapp.ui.activity.webviews.OpenAnyDocActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Else If you want to load these files then use Specific app with intent or add different software.

1. For .doc, .xls, .ppt type : use Apache POI
2. For Mov use - Exo player
3. For JPG, PNG GIF use Glide.

Comment: I used butterknife by JAKE Warthon for UI binding.